# Civilization formation?

Tags: humans, civilization

In my Kepler Bb story, I go from individual level to family level to civilization level.

This is how I was planning my civilization:

1) Alma(Robin and Lisa's child) when she is 17, tells Planetary Leader 1 to send 50 unrelated people in a 1:1 gender ratio with a minimum age of 15.

2) Alma, Lisa, and Robin give a presentation about the species, the form of their home, civilization plans, and even their powers.

3) 25 homes are built, each one being different and customized to them. Robin builds all of what goes in the homes. Likewise women marry the men they love.

4) Birth and pregnancy rate are the main focus for about 100-300 years(Kepler Bb years that is, not earth years).

5) Business becomes more and more common but is still free or barter

6) A pirate and his crew go out to sea and find out that throughout the planet, gold and silver are common. Kepler B# civilizations can form gold and silver in case they run out. Now a currency is formed with gold being more valuable.

7) Robin becomes mayor and starts planning underground streets.

8) Eventually, one of Robin's descendants decides to become president.

I don't know if I will go any further than this and if I will I don't know what is going to happen.

Anyway, I was wondering how I should go about this civilization formation.

So do you have any suggestions as to how I should go about this civilization formation? I am working on a Kepler Bb world map region by region.

Answer (score 6):

This is adorable :D

Fifty people might just be enough to get a civilisation started but the lack of genetic diversity is going to cause all sorts of problems. In the generations to come parents will need to have lots of children, many will die before or soon after birth. Those with debilitating genetic disorders will need to be killed, this fledgling society will not have the means to support cripples and invalids. The degeneration of the gene pool can be lessened somewhat by women bearing children with multiple partners, to this end (assuming there can only be 50 people) about 10 males to 40 females would be better.

More women, more children, equals a greater chance that the next generation will have sufficient genetically fit adults to continue the process. Any semblance of monogamy in this situation is absurd, the males won't have committed relationships with four wives, for the sake of genetic diversity every female should reproduce with every male at least once.

Twenty or so generations later a civilisation of hideous stupid and nearly blind people will be able to look forward to a brighter future for their still vaguely human offspring, assuming a viral infection doesn't wipe them out.

Comment: But the fact that the fifty people are completely unrelated means that each generation is more and more likely to get more and more genetically diverse. And I don't see how more breeding per possible M/F pair is better in this situation. These people are very family orientated and without monogamy, people will become murderous whereas with monogamy murder would be very much under control due to there being at least 1 parent at any given time with the child(usually the mom for the first 5 years).

Comment: And wet nurses are very low priority at this point(Pregnancy is much higher priority). So preemies before 34 weeks would most likely die anyway, even if Robin was able to produce breast pumps that connect to nasogastric tubes due to suction not really developing to the strength needed for nursing. Postmature babies would more likely survive since they are more developed and these females have super elastic birth canals that allow even the biggest babies to be born without surgery.

Comment: @Caters: "*But the fact that the fifty people are completely unrelated means that each generation is more and more likely to get more and more genetically diverse.*" ... that's not the way genetic diversity works. Mutation rates don't increase based on the number of people around. "*without monogamy, people will become murderous*" ... um, what? I don't buy that one at all.

Comment: My momma said that if I want murderous people, then sure no monogamy, but if you want caring, family oriented people, you should have monogamy between mother and father, even if it is only for a few years. And what I was saying involved genetic crossover in both the male and the female whereas you are simplifying it into a simple mitosis.

Comment: And that last paragraph is completely unfounded. I mean, vaguely human? And what says only the worst qualities will survive?

Answer (score 0):

50 start the first colony. Few Generations later a few groups leave colony to explore planet. One are these groups can a later become your pirate band. These groups  form their own colonies,  villages towns and crime dens. A few more Generations and as for unification movement formed trying to unite all these scattered because the one single nation. Unification movement succeeds and elects its first president.